# Slideshow not showing the left/right arrows

Tags: jquery, slideshow, arrows

I have four slideshows on my website, and before I added the jQuery function Backstretch, they were all working fine. Now the left and right arrows appear circular and black - but when the arrow image is dragged into a new tab you can see it as it should be.

Here is my slideshow code:

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<center>

<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>

<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<style>
.mySlides {display:none}
</style>
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
</div>
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width: 771px;">

  <img class="mySlides" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-M7Z6DU_4rr4/WH854ptAAnI/AAAAAAAAfxk/lT87QTRG-K8IV_KT0bp4rNOpdI2c2Z3xgCLcB/s1600/A.jpg" style="width: 771px;" />
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-os3VKF2UqTY/WH86xNs-pjI/AAAAAAAAfzk/vbnk731lmio-YwBYtybdtyEwLWR2H0HuQCLcB/s1600/Z25.jpg" style="width: 771px;" />
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-q-mfkdFqElk/WH86yBXX2nI/AAAAAAAAfzo/GT8IOltOyho76hyksDTl89L9yJ2pfG0mwCLcB/s1600/Z30.jpg" style="width: 771px;" />


<a class="w3-btn-floating" onclick="plusDivs(-1)" style="left: 0; position: absolute; top: 45%;"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9TRFDOt59CI/Vz4EANpBSuI/AAAAAAAAdbY/wn8hFl3KfGAdq5jqeE1XZ00STJDBPaRoQCLcB/s1600/left.png" style="height: 22px; width: 16px;" /></a>
<a class="w3-btn-floating" onclick="plusDivs(1)" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 45%;"><img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-0oFX79ip8cY/Vz4EAMYwacI/AAAAAAAAdbU/429-hZhCwhAEZOWn7bqVb1Ze7Ub0h-1FgCLcB/s1600/right.png" style="height: 22px; width: 16px;" /></a>

</div>
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-border-red", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-border-black";
}
</script>

</body>
</html> 
</center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, you just need to add **z-index property to your arrow images** so that it is rendered over the image and i also have commented the dots element since there was none as of now.

Here is the working snippet

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-border-red", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
 // dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-border-black";
// since you dont have any element with name demo this returns error
}
```

```css
            .mySlides {
                display: none
            }
```

```html
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
    <center>

        <html>
        <title>W3.CSS</title>

        <link href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

        <body>

            <div class="w3-container/">
            <div class="w3-content" style="max-width: 771px;">

                <img class="mySlides" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-M7Z6DU_4rr4/WH854ptAAnI/AAAAAAAAfxk/lT87QTRG-K8IV_KT0bp4rNOpdI2c2Z3xgCLcB/s1600/A.jpg"
                    style="width: 771px;" />
                <img class="mySlides" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-os3VKF2UqTY/WH86xNs-pjI/AAAAAAAAfzk/vbnk731lmio-YwBYtybdtyEwLWR2H0HuQCLcB/s1600/Z25.jpg"
                    style="width: 771px;" />
                <img class="mySlides" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-q-mfkdFqElk/WH86yBXX2nI/AAAAAAAAfzo/GT8IOltOyho76hyksDTl89L9yJ2pfG0mwCLcB/s1600/Z30.jpg"
                    style="width: 771px;" />


                <a class="w3-btn-floating" onclick="plusDivs(-1)" style="left: 0; position: absolute; top: 45%; z-index: 2;"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9TRFDOt59CI/Vz4EANpBSuI/AAAAAAAAdbY/wn8hFl3KfGAdq5jqeE1XZ00STJDBPaRoQCLcB/s1600/left.png"
                        style="height: 22px; width: 16px;" /></a>
                <a class="w3-btn-floating" onclick="plusDivs(1)" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 45%; z-index: 2;"><img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-0oFX79ip8cY/Vz4EAMYwacI/AAAAAAAAdbU/429-hZhCwhAEZOWn7bqVb1Ze7Ub0h-1FgCLcB/s1600/right.png"
                        style="height: 22px; width: 16px;" /></a>

            </div>

        </body>

        </html>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm afraid I must be too tired to think clearly (or generally too inexperienced) - I copy and pasted the code, as is, onto my website and it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: whatever code you have shared it's working as you can see in the snippet here, if there is any other problem please share the exact problem

Comment: Yes, I can see that the code you provided does work (when I click "run code snippet") but when I copy and paste it onto my blog, in the order it's in in your post, it doesn't work.

Comment: in that case unless you share what exactly your code is doing or where are you copy pasting it, I am afraid i wont be able to help

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain... If I just edit my own code, adding the z-index, it doesn't change anything - the arrows are still black circles. Then if I copy and paste what you provided into my Blogger page, the photos just appear one on top of the other (the middle image has the arrows next to it; but which don't do anything and are still black circles) and the top part of the code in your post (from var slideIndex = 1; to   x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";) appears above the images.

Comment: try checking the console in your browser, it must be throwing some error

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to use the console?

Comment: on windows if you press ctrl+shift+i it will open developer tools which will have console tab.